# Can Node.js's clustering feature leverage multiple CPUs?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I buy a dual cpu motherboard that runs two 16 core cpus. Would this return 32?

```
const os = require('os')
const cpuCount = os.cpus().length // 32
```

And could I use Node.js Cluster to leverage all 32 cores, or would the extra CPU not be recognized / Node.js be unable to leverage a second processor?

Comment: Answer is in the first lines in their documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html (Yes)

Comment: @limido can you paste the quote you're referring to? The first paragraph refers to "multi-core" systems which is different from "multi cpu" systems. It doesn't explicitly say it supports two or more processors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if your OS can "see" both physical CPUs correctly, then there's no reason `os.cpus().length` should return anything but the sum of the number of logical cores from both CPUs.

Comment: @ethane yeah you'd think but that's an expensive test if we're wrong. I've been scouring google for anyone mentioning actually doing this and can't seem to find an example confirming it works.

Comment: Perhaps you could try asking on NodeJS's GitHub repo. I don't imagine this is a very common setup for most servers. Nevertheless, it would be very interesting to see the actual results.

https://github.com/nodejs/node

Comment: what is the output of CPU(s) in `lscpu`? it should be the same with node - logical CPU : https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus

Comment: @ethane I'll try asking there. I have a weird feeling about it because if it worked well it seems like it would be more common. If your bottleneck is CPU and you're leveraging all cores efficiently, it seems like a common solution for server infrastructure would be to grab boards with 2 or 4 cpu sockets to save on the peripheral costs, like 1 slightly more expensive mobo instead of 2, 1 case instead of 2, 1 slightly more expensive power supply instead of two... seems like with node being so popular you'd see people talking about using the setup if it worked..

Comment: relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0il7xdpUPB8